# Use SQL SELECT query to return a minimum number of users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm a little new to using SQL and was wondering if someone might be able to help me with this query I'm trying to figure out. I'm developing a Wordpress theme and something I'd like to do in it is generate a random set of users on a page by using a SELECT query. It works great right now, I have it randomly pulling users from the database and displaying them with the right formatting. I can even limit the number of users (using the LIMIT clause) or order them by user properties.

However, my challenge is in getting the query to return at least 4 users (sometimes `RAND()` function causes only 2 to be displayed, which isn't great for a front-facing page).

I don't want to create a query that will throw an error if there are less than four users (which there will never be, but I'd still want to write clean code).

So, in summary:
SELECT query that returns exactly 4 results, randomly ordered and, and doesn't throw an error if there's less than four users.

Any thoughts? I've tried using a few different ways to give RAND() different parameters and looked to see if there's a 'minimum' clause, but I haven't found anything. It's also a bit of a strange query bc most of the time we're more concerned with upper than lower limits.

Thanks everyone!

Here's the code I have in a custom.php file (I'm using the Roots starter theme):

```
function wpb_random_users() {

global $wpdb;


// Query database for users, change the number of users displayed by changing the limit
$usernames = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_nicename, user_url, user_email FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4 ");

// Display users in a list
foreach ($usernames as $username) {

if (!$username->user_url) :
$randomusers .= '<div class="col-md-3">'.'<img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="'.get_wp_user_avatar_src($username->user_email, 'thumbnail').'" alt="" />'.'<h4>'.$username->user_nicename.'</h4>'.'</div>';

endif;
}

return $randomusers;
}

add_shortcode('randomusers','wpb_random_users');
```

Comment: **Edit**: I know that I don't have to pass RAND() anything; removing the passed variable to reflect the current state of the solution I am trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL query is not the reason you're getting less than 4 results... You should get 4 every time, provided there's at least 4 rows in the table.

I suggest you debug this line: `if (!$username->user_url) :`. You are displaying only users with no URL. So, if you get 4 users back from the SQL query, but only two of them lack a URL, you only get 2 users.

Incidentally, you don't need to seed the `rand()` function for what you're doing. In fact, it's less desirable. Just use `SELECT user_nicename, user_url, user_email FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4 ");`

Comment: Just edited to reflect the unnecessary variable I had left in there when I pasted in my code (I'd deleted it from source after pasting). 

Ah! I think you might be right about the URL issue; I'll see what happens when they all have URL's. Forgot about that parameter—thanks! Good catch!

Comment: Just out of curiosity; do you know of any cases where a minimum number of results can be made to return? Even though I now know it doesn't relate to my question, I'm curious if that's ever desirable/a good practice.

Comment: MySQL will always return the maximum number of rows you request. It will only return less than the LIMIT if there are less rows than the LIMIT in the table... So, there's not a way to set a "minimum..." that would require MySQL to give you the same row twice if it was running out of rows to give you, which is all kinds of problematic.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Problem solved. 

The culprits were leftovers from a version of the function when it was helpful to use if/else statements to determine if there were user URL's present or not. 

By removing the if and end if (as well as passed params) statements, I was able to get the query to work correctly. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Interesting; that makes sense. Besides, that use-case sounds like it might never exist. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the rand() function description. You don't need to pass argument to the function just do:

```
$usernames = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `user_nicename`, `user_url`, `user_email` FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
```

Remember that rand() function isn't effective so if you have large amount of data there are better solutions.

Rand() function is invoked for every row in table.

If you have at least 4 users the query will return them. You can debug to see with following code before foreach

```
print_r($usernames);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: I've already tried that. Because of the way the rand() func. works, it sometimes returns less than 4 users, which is the exact problem I am trying to overcome.

Do you know of another way to return at least 4 users?

Comment: With the query if you have at least 4 users it will show them. There's nothing wrong in the query you can test in in phpmyadmin. You can pay attention to your if clause because if there is no user url then it won't be displayed

Comment: Robert is right. You do not need to seed the rand() function. Read the documentation. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html Furthermore, rand() is not the reason you are getting less than 4 results. It's in an order by clause, not a where clause.

Comment: @John's answer above is above the same lines; I'll try that see if that works. Feeling silly for forgetting about that param. Thanks!

Comment: Changed the code above to reflect rand() with no seeding; I actually had read the docs and found that out, but hadn't deleted it yet when pasting it over; sorry about that! :)

Answer (score 0):

To get a random ordering in SQL:

```
select a, b, c
from(
    select a, b, c, rand() OrderBy
    from tablename
)
order by OrderBy;
```

That will give you a table dump in random order. You want only up to 4 rows. There are two places you can put the limit and the results will be different depending on where you put it.

```
select a, b, c
from(
    select a, b, c, rand() OrderBy
    from tablename
    limit 4
)
order by OrderBy;
```

That will give you the same 4 rows, just shuffled around.

```
select a, b, c
from(
    select a, b, c, rand() OrderBy
    from tablename
)
order by OrderBy
limit 4;
```

That will give you 4 random rows from within the entire table. This seems to be what you want but it's still not very efficient as it also has to scan the entire table. A compromise would be to limit the inline view to a reasonable set that provides at least 4 rows but not so many more as to be terribly inefficient. Say the inline view generates 40 rows. That means the following will pull 4 random rows from the same set of 40. That is probably close enough for your needs.

```
select a, b, c
from(
    select a, b, c, rand() OrderBy
    from tablename
    where some-limiting-factor -- generates about 40 rows
)
order by OrderBy
limit 4;
```